# How do I simulate multiple table captions?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to make a CSS table that (for layout purposes) has a caption at the top and bottom.

Unfortunately, [as far as I can tell](http://jsfiddle.net/fCTpR/), `display: table-caption` merges everything into a single space at the top.  This means that only the "header" caption is actually displayed.

[I've tried treating them as rows instead](http://jsfiddle.net/QjA2h/), but for some reason, their widths bind to that of the first table column.  (Am I doing something wrong here?)  The same happens if I make them regular `div`s with their widths set to `100%`.

Is there another, perhaps more elegant way to have multiple table captions?  Have I made some stupid error in my attempts that's screwing up the layout?

Comment: Treating them like rows creates an implicit `display:table-cell`; without a `colspan` (that you can't set in CSS) they will always be part of the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using CSS for layout (this is not tabular data) then there's no reason to use `display:table-caption` for the footer. Just make a regular div whose width is set to the same as the table (or fills a container that shrink-wraps the table).

**Edit**: Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/fCTpR/1/

Comment: Although this answer styles the table appropriately, it does not convey the semantics necessary for accessibility.